# Wordpress 'posts_per_page' not working on global $wp_query on front-page.php

Tags: wordpress

In my Wordpress admin panel, in the section 'Settings' -> 'Reading', I have set the 'Blog pages show at most' value as 5 and I have the 'Your homepage displays' value set to 'Your latest posts'.
I am trying to bypass this on my front-page.php loop by setting the 'posts_per_page' argument of the query to 2 (or any number other than 5) and I haven't added a 'pre_get_posts' hook in my functions.php file. But the result always shows 5 posts.

This is my front-page.php file:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php
global $wp_query;
$wp_query->set('posts_per_page', 2);
if ($wp_query->have_posts()) {
    while ($wp_query->have_posts()) {
        //var_dump($wp_query->get('post_type'));
        $wp_query->the_post();
        the_title();
        echo '<br>';
    }
    echo paginate_links();
}
?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Kindly let me know how I can bypass the value that I have set in the admin panel.

Thank You,
Clement

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the below code -

```
$MY_Posts = array( 
    'posts_per_page' => 3, 
    'orderby' => 'date', 
    'order' => 'DESC', 
    'update_post_term_cache' => false, 
    'update_post_meta_cache' => false, 
    'nopaging' => true, 
); 
$the_query = new WP_Query( $MY_Posts );
```

Comment: I know I can achieve this by creating my own WP_Query object like you've shown. But I want to achieve this with the global $wp_query object. Is that not possible?

Comment: Ok, You can try with below code for this, add the below code in the function.php file. Maybe it will work for you - 

function custom_posts_per_page( $query ) {
    if (  is_page(PAGEID)  ) {
        set_query_var('posts_per_page', 2);
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_posts_per_page' );